# android - galley with Picasso or Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, performance, picasso, universal-image-loader

I am trying to make a gallery using GridView + Picasso\Universal Image Loader and I faced with some problems. Every time I load only **local** files (from external storage), not from the web. I make two videos, that describe the problems much better, then words.

I use my custom adapter extends `BaseAdapter`.

`thumbs` is an array of `File` with images

#### Picasso

Loads images quickly enough, but very slow scrolling.[Here the video demonstration on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJyduLvMNLE&feature=youtu.be)

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Get the view
    View view;
    if (convertView == null)
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_photo_item,parent,false);
    else
        view =  convertView;

    //find the componetnts
    final ImageView image_view = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.galley_photo_item_image);
    final CheckBox check = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.galley_photo_item_checkbox);

    //Toggling checkbox if DELETE MODE
    if(is_checking) {
        check.setChecked(false);
        check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
        check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    view.setTag(position);
    check.setTag(position);

    //Some event handling
    check.setOnClickListener(this);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Setting up Picasso
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
    builder.listener(new com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            Log.e("Picasso","Loading failed: "+exception.getMessage());
            image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });

    //Display image
    Picasso pic = builder.build();
    pic
            .load(thumbs[position])
            //.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .into(image_view);


    return view;
}
```

#### Universal Image Loader

Scrolling quickly, but loading is slow. Also when you scroll fast, you can see the wrong images, which will replace by correct (when they've loaded) for a few seconds. [Demonstration on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ukAxlvwyqhg)

I added the `View Holder` pattern here.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder view_holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_photo_item,parent,false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.galley_photo_item_image);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.galley_photo_item_checkbox);
        view_holder = new ViewHolder(convertView,image,checkBox);
        convertView.setTag(view_holder);
    }
    else
        view_holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    //Toggle checkbox on DELETE MODE
    if(is_checking) {
        view_holder.CheckBox.setChecked(false);
        view_holder.CheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
        view_holder.CheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //view.setTag(position);
    //check.setTag(position);

    //Event handling
    view_holder.CheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    view_holder.View.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Display image
    String uri = Uri.fromFile(thumbs[position]).toString();
    ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    loader.displayImage(uri,view_holder.ImageView, options);


    return convertView;
}
```

#### Question

What is good way to make gallery working faster (as a native android app, perfectly)?

Comment: Don't create a new picasso instance each time getView is called; use the singleton instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using Glide Image Loader Library its recommended by google
Refer here:-  https://coderzpassion.com/android-working-glide-image-loader-library/

Comment: Thanks, Glide is qutie fast. First loadig is a bit slow, but then It works really fast.

Comment: Yeah, also check material design post  i found very interesting